# How can I form my dataframe so that each row with same id becomes one row and the values change into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, multiple-columns

So i have data in the following dataframe:

|  | id | hours1 | hours2 | id_2 | status | timeweeks | code1 | code2 | code3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 858 | 2.087e+06 | 105 | 14 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 96.7143 | nan | nan | 0.5 |
| 505 | 2.08697e+06 | 0 | 28 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 111.143 | nan | 0.5 | nan |
| 245 | 2.08695e+06 | 32 | 431.5 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 178.571 | nan | nan | 5 |
| 620 | 2.08698e+06 | 10 | 0 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 103.571 | nan | 0.5 | nan |
| 177 | 1.90024e+06 | 60 | 57 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 37.7143 | nan | nan | 0.5 |
| 828 | 2.08699e+06 | 112 | 0 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 129.714 | nan | nan | 0.5 |
| 63 | 1.58152e+06 | 1252 | 65.25 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 94 | nan | nan | 3 |
| 479 | 2.08697e+06 | 0 | 56 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 62.4286 | nan | nan | 0 |
| 251 | 2.08695e+06 | 32 | 431.5 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 178.571 | nan | 4 | nan |
| 673 | 2.08698e+06 | 0 | 7 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 103.571 | nan | nan | 0.5 |
| 310 | 2.08695e+06 | 105 | 53 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 58 | nan | nan | 0.5 |
| 336 | 2.08696e+06 | 77 | 77 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 113.286 | nan | nan | 0.5 |
| 731 | 2.08699e+06 | 229.25 | 105.75 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 116.286 | nan | 5 | nan |
| 72 | 1.58152e+06 | 1252 | 65.25 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 94 | nan | nan | 0.5 |
| 800 | 2.08699e+06 | 112 | 0 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 129.714 | nan | nan | 0.5 |
| 674 | 2.08698e+06 | 0 | 7 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 103.571 | nan | nan | 0.5 |
| 402 | 2.08696e+06 | 0 | 7 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 103.571 | nan | nan | 0.5 |
| 606 | 2.08698e+06 | 10 | 0 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 103.571 | nan | nan | 0.5 |
| 804 | 2.08699e+06 | 112 | 0 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 129.714 | nan | nan | 0.5 |
| 513 | 2.08697e+06 | 0 | 28 | 1.057e+06 | 1 | 111.143 | nan | 0.5 | nan |

and I basically want it to be in shape that in one row is data of one id. So in one row there would be only one value of the next columns: id, hours1, hours2, id_2, status and timeweeks. And then every code value of one id would be its own column. Or if its somehow possible, only the notnull value of each rows  three code columns would be column. So the final dataframe should look like this:

| id | hours1 | hours2 | id_2 | status | timeweeks | code1_1 | code2_1 | code3_1 | code3_2 | and so on.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 105 | 200 | 1 | 1 | 50 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 5 |  |
| 2 | 300 | 40 | 1 | 1 | 33 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 3 | 20 | 30 | 2 | 5 | 20 | 0 | 0.5 | 2 | 2 |  |

Don't really know if it's even possible this way, but I want to think it is.

So what I tried was turning them into dict and then after that back to dataframe.

I tested this:

```
df_test2 = df_2.groupby(['id','id2','hours1','hours2', 'status','timeweeks'])[['code1','code2','code3']].apply(lambda g: g.values.tolist()).to_dict()
```

and got result (one item):

```
{(1564719, 1057033.0, 407.5, 123.5, 99.71428406084657, 1.0): [[nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 1.0], [nan, nan, 4.0], [nan, nan, 2.0], [nan, nan, 2.0], [nan, nan, 2.0], [nan, nan, 4.0], [nan, nan, 2.0], [nan, nan, 3.0], [nan, nan, 2.0], [nan, nan, 1.0], [nan, nan, 4.0], [nan, nan, 5.0], [nan, nan, 2.0], [nan, nan, 4.0], [nan, nan, 2.0], [nan, nan, 2.0], [nan, nan, 2.0], [nan, nan, 2.0], [nan, nan, 2.0], [nan, 1.0, nan], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, 4.0, nan], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, 1.0, nan], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, 4.0, nan], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5], [nan, nan, 0.5]]
```

after that put it to dataframe like this:

```
testframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_test3,orient='index')
```

It looks like this:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 | 40 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55 | 56 | 57 | 58 | 59 | 60 | 61 | 62 | 63 | 64 | 65 | 66 | 67 | 68 | 69 | 70 | 71 | 72 | 73 | 74 | 75 | 76 | 77 | 78 | 79 | 80 | 81 | 82 | 83 | 84 | 85 | 86 | 87 | 88 | 89 | 90 | 91 | 92 | 93 | 94 | 95 | 96 | 97 | 98 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 | 105 | 106 | 107 | 108 | 109 | 110 | 111 | 112 | 113 | 114 | 115 | 116 | 117 | 118 | 119 | 120 | 121 | 122 | 123 | 124 | 125 | 126 | 127 | 128 | 129 | 130 | 131 | 132 | 133 | 134 | 135 | 136 | 137 | 138 | 139 | 140 | 141 | 142 | 143 | 144 | 145 | 146 | 147 | 148 | 149 | 150 | 151 | 152 | 153 | 154 | 155 | 156 | 157 | 158 | 159 | 160 | 161 | 162 | 163 | 164 | 165 | 166 | 167 | 168 | 169 | 170 | 171 | 172 | 173 | 174 | 175 | 176 | 177 | 178 | 179 | 180 | 181 | 182 | 183 | 184 | 185 | 186 | 187 | 188 | 189 | 190 | 191 | 192 | 193 | 194 | 195 | 196 | 197 | 198 | 199 | 200 | 201 | 202 | 203 | 204 | 205 | 206 | 207 | 208 | 209 | 210 | 211 | 212 | 213 | 214 | 215 | 216 | 217 | 218 | 219 | 220 | 221 | 222 | 223 | 224 | 225 | 226 | 227 | 228 | 229 | 230 | 231 | 232 | 233 | 234 | 235 | 236 | 237 | 238 | 239 | 240 | 241 | 242 | 243 | 244 | 245 | 246 | 247 | 248 | 249 | 250 | 251 | 252 | 253 | 254 | 255 | 256 | 257 | 258 | 259 | 260 | 261 | 262 | 263 | 264 | 265 | 266 | 267 | 268 | 269 | 270 | 271 | 272 | 273 | 274 | 275 | 276 | 277 | 278 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (1564719, 1057033.0, 407.5, 123.5, 99.71428406084657, 1.0) | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 1.0] | [nan, nan, 4.0] | [nan, nan, 2.0] | [nan, nan, 2.0] | [nan, nan, 2.0] | [nan, nan, 4.0] | [nan, nan, 2.0] | [nan, nan, 3.0] | [nan, nan, 2.0] | [nan, nan, 1.0] | [nan, nan, 4.0] | [nan, nan, 5.0] | [nan, nan, 2.0] | [nan, nan, 4.0] | [nan, nan, 2.0] | [nan, nan, 2.0] | [nan, nan, 2.0] | [nan, nan, 2.0] | [nan, nan, 2.0] | [nan, 1.0, nan] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, 4.0, nan] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, 1.0, nan] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, 4.0, nan] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| (1581517, 1057003.0, 1252.0, 65.25, 93.99999834656084, 1.0) | [nan, nan, nan] | [nan, nan, 3.0] | [nan, nan, 3.0] | [nan, nan, 5.0] | [nan, nan, 3.0] | [nan, nan, 5.0] | [nan, nan, 5.0] | [nan, nan, 5.0] | [nan, nan, 3.0] | [nan, nan, 3.0] | [nan, nan, 3.0] | [nan, nan, 5.0] | [nan, 3.0, nan] | [nan, 3.0, nan] | [nan, 3.0, nan] | [nan, 3.0, nan] | [nan, 3.0, nan] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 0.5] | [nan, nan, 1.0] | [nan, 3.0, nan] | [nan, nan, 5.0] | [nan, nan, 3.0] | [nan, nan, 5.0] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

which is not exactly what I was aiming for.
So if there is way to make dataframe look like in the example, that would be my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for remove misisng values after [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then create helper columns and level in `MultiIndex` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and last reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
cols = ['id','id_2','hours1','hours2', 'status','timeweeks']
df1 = df.set_index(cols).stack().to_frame('code')

df1 = df1.set_index(df1.groupby(df1.index).cumcount().add(1), append=True)['code'].unstack([-1,-2])
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df1)
           id       id_2   hours1  hours2  status  timeweeks  code3_1  \
0   1581520.0  1057000.0  1252.00   65.25       1    94.0000      3.0   
1   1900240.0  1057000.0    60.00   57.00       1    37.7143      0.5   
2   2086950.0  1057000.0    32.00  431.50       1   178.5710      5.0   
3   2086950.0  1057000.0   105.00   53.00       1    58.0000      0.5   
4   2086960.0  1057000.0     0.00    7.00       1   103.5710      0.5   
5   2086960.0  1057000.0    77.00   77.00       1   113.2860      0.5   
6   2086970.0  1057000.0     0.00   28.00       1   111.1430      NaN   
7   2086970.0  1057000.0     0.00   56.00       1    62.4286      0.0   
8   2086980.0  1057000.0     0.00    7.00       1   103.5710      0.5   
9   2086980.0  1057000.0    10.00    0.00       1   103.5710      0.5   
10  2086990.0  1057000.0   112.00    0.00       1   129.7140      0.5   
11  2086990.0  1057000.0   229.25  105.75       1   116.2860      NaN   
12  2087000.0  1057000.0   105.00   14.00       1    96.7143      0.5   

    code2_1  code3_2  code3_3  code2_2  
0       NaN      0.5      NaN      NaN  
1       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
2       4.0      NaN      NaN      NaN  
3       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
4       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
5       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
6       0.5      NaN      NaN      0.5  
7       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  
8       NaN      0.5      NaN      NaN  
9       0.5      NaN      NaN      NaN  
10      NaN      0.5      0.5      NaN  
11      5.0      NaN      NaN      NaN  
12      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: This seemed to work well. Thanks!